# Как сделать затухающие полоски?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как на картинке по краям

Как на картинке по краям

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать `linear-gradient` для `background`.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```